# No module named object_detection on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

I am running Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine. I installed object_detection through the terminal in the directory ~/models/research/

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Then adding libraries to PYTHONPATH (still in the same directory ~/models/research/)

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

And (still in the same directory ~/models/research/) successfully tested that it is installed using:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

But when I try to import it in jupyter notebook, it returns the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'.

Note: I run my jupyter notebook through the terminal in the ~ directory. And python version is 3.6

Also, don't know if this is related, but whenever I restart my virtual machine and run the code above to test installation of object_detection, it fails. And I have to re-install it using the above steps.

Comment: Did you install the module `object_detection` to your environment?

Comment: No, just followed the above steps. How do I install it to my environment? (I'm a kinda a noob)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Jupyter PYTHONPATH appears to be different. I add the following to the start of the script.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

This should work.